# How to Merge seperated JS file, CSS file and HTML file together?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript. I need a CSS text animation to setup a part of my website. Here I found an attractive animation `link is in the 3rd comment because stackoverflow doesn't allow me to put the link here (keep showing an error)`

When I copy these HTML code, CSS code and JS code and create a webpage including them, It doesn't work properly. Actually no any animation.

How can I solve this to work?

Comment: you can use multiple `<script>` and `<link>` tags in HTML.

Comment: Press F12 on your browser to see what error you are getting.Are you including the necessary libraries?

Comment: **The Link :** http://codepen.io/JustusFT/pen/ENLZGJ

Comment: @Rafed Muhammad Yasir yes think they already included all the libraries. But I haven't check for any error in console. I'll check that

Comment: The JS is using jQuery. The html code shown there does not include it. Have you include the jQuery?

Comment: @Rafed Muhammad Yasir yes of course I added JQ library. Checked for errors in the console and no error.

Comment: The CSS shown is SCSS, not just plain CSS. SCSS is compiled into CSS. Did you notice this ? If you copied the SCSS into a CSS file, the demo might very well not work at all.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Quentin I have tried many times to put the link into the question and stackoverflow didn't let me put the link. It keep saying the link should be quoted as a code (using 4 spaces) even after I set it as a code. Then I put it in my comment.

Comment: @SachiniPrasadika — You're supposed to put **the code in the question**. You aren't supposed to just link to it.

Comment: @Quentin - Yes I understand. I put the link here because that linked page shows the result too which I can't generate anywhere. I thought It'll help someone to understand what exactly I'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Option :

- Signup in the codepen.io
- Goto your link
- Click on the Export button at the right bottom corner
- Select Export.zip
- After download the zip file, unzip it
- Open index.html and you'll see the result.
- Check the code of index.html for the missing codes

Answer (score 1):

**For javascript**

Make script tag and copy all the JavaScript between it.

```
<script>...</script>
```

**For css**

Make a style tag and copy all the CSS between it.

```
<style>...</style>
```

And to fix your problems double check your code and see whether you are missing some library or not.

The codepen project us using jquery, font-awesome and other things. This will help you import some of them.

`<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/230e98b440.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">`